# Installing python-docx on pycharm 2017

Tags: python, installation, python-docx

I am having real trouble with this. Wasted a bunch of hours and just can't get it figured out. I would appreciate any help.

I have installed python-docx on Pycharm. I run the following code:

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
```

And i receive the following error message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Document'
```

I have seen a number of different explanations ... need to update lxml, need to update PIL need to check source folder ... and I have not been able to make anything work and it is becoming very frustrating.

I am on a MAC OS X 10.10.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty good chance you have 'docx' installed rather than 'python-docx'. 'docx' was the package name for the legacy version, v0.2 and before. It has a completely different API and doesn't have a `Document` class. Consequently it gives this exact error. If `python-docx` just wasn't installed it would be more like `no package named docx`.

You can confirm this with `pip freeze`:

```
$ pip freeze
...
docx=0.2.0
...
python-docx=0.8.6
...
```

You can only have one installed; they can't co-exist because the root module name is `docx` in both cases. Which one gets imported as `docx` depends on installation order and perhaps other factors; short story is you should get rid of the old one.

Depending on what `pip freeze` shows you, you'll want to uninstall `docx` and install or reinstall `python-docx`. Safest would be to uninstall them both and then reinstall `python-docx`.

```
$ pip uninstall docx
$ pip uninstall python-docx
$ pip install python-docx
```

Comment: definitely had both modules. this did work for a live instance of Python BUT i am still have the same error message when I try to run python-docx in pycharm. Any reason why that would be the case?

Comment: for the record, i looked in the docx folder under site-packages for Python3.5 and i can see the Document.py file. i can not see any other instances of docx.

Comment: It's very possible that PyCharm maintains its own "private" Python installation. You'll want to check that separately: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#d64763e217. Make sure you vote up this answer if it was helpful to you and accept it if you consider it the "right" answer. That's how respondents get "paid" for their efforts here on SO.

Comment: thanks for feedback. figured it out. apparently you are not supposed to name your working files after the programs you are using! wasted weeks on that! #lifeasanoob

Comment: Ah, yes, I'd forgotten that one :) That bit me early on, I remember now :)

Answer (score 0):

scanny is right. The only problem I had was that after uninstalling both docx and python-docx with pip (pip3 on Mac), and then reinstalling only python-docx, I still couldn't get the module working on Pycharm. I then realised I had to uninstall docx from inside Pycharm (Pycharm -> Preferences -> Project Interpreter (on left panel) -> click on docx (on right side) and click minus button at the bottom to uninstall docx). The python-docx was already there (if it wasn't, I would have had to install it by clicking the plus button and selecting python-docx from the long list that appears). After this, the module was working perfectly on my Pycharm.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem be changing the import to this:

```
from document import Document
```

Other solutions didn't work for me.